# Не работает random.choice для файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, случайные-числа

Не работает random.choice файла

```
def photos(user_id): 
    a = vk.method("photos.getMessagesUploadServer") 
    b = requests.post(a['upload_url'], files={'photo':open(random.choice(screen), 'rb')}).json() 
    c = vk.method('photos.saveMessagesPhoto', {'photo': b['photo'], 'server': b['server'], 'hash': b['hash']})[0] 
    d = "photo{}_{}".format(c["owner_id"], c["id"]) 
    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": user_id, "attachment": d})
```

open(random.choice(screen) - проблема в том, что мне нужно выбрать рандомную картинку из папки (все файлы там - картинки в png формате) и оно просто не выдает рандом. Если я делаю без рандома и пишу именно имя конкретного файла, то все работает.

пробовал выбирать через *os.listdir* и пробовал засунуть значение os.listdir в переменую уже через нее рандом

сейчас в массиве содержится список имен файлов и он выбирает уже рандом из этого, но тоже не работает

Comment: Добрый вечер! А причем тут вообще боты и вк? :) У вас проблема с `random.choice(screen)`, т.е. с тем что не получается получить случайное значение. Но вы не написали что передается в `random.choice`. Вопрос ведь нужно оформлять по существу, а то что проблема возникла при написании бота, не является важной инфой. Т.е. на ваш вопрос ответа нет, т.к. нет данных для воспроизведения проблемы. Вашему вопросу нехватает [минимального, самодостаточного и воспроизводимова примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `random.choice` передаете список файлов, чтобы он вернул случайный элемент.

Для этого можно использовать `glob`:

```
import glob

...

def photos(user_id, file_name):
    upload_url = vk.method("photos.getMessagesUploadServer")['upload_url']
    rs = requests.post(upload_url, files={'photo': open(file_name, 'rb')}).json()
    data = vk.method('photos.saveMessagesPhoto', rs)[0]
    
    attachment = "photo{}_{}".format(data["owner_id"], data["id"])
    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": user_id, "attachment": attachment})


...

file_name = random.choice(glob.glob('images/*.png'))
photos(user_id, file_name)
```

---

Для `os.listdir` код будет похожим:

```
...

DIR_IMAGE = 'images'

file_name = random.choice(os.listdir(DIR_IMAGE))
file_name = os.path.join(DIR_IMAGE, file_name)

photos(user_id, file_name)
```

Только, нужно быть осторожным, т.к. `os.listdir`, в отличии от `glob`, вернет только названия файлов и папок, без самой папки.

Если у вас картинки находятся в `images`: `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png`, то `os.listdir('images')` вернет `['1.png', '2.png', '3.png']`, но ожидалось что будет путь к картинке, т.е. `['images/1.png', 'images/2.png', 'images/3.png']` из-за чего картинка не найдется.

Поэтому нужна вторая часть с `os.path.join`, чтобы к названию файла добавить его папку, чтобы путь стал полным.

А `glob.glob('images/*.png')` вернет ожидаемый `['images/1.png', 'images/2.png', 'images/3.png']`, причем позволит сразу задать фильтр по формату.

---

**PS.** можно попросить `glob` вернуть и без конкретного формата: `glob.glob('images/*.*')`, или попросить вернуть все `glob.glob('images/*')`

Comment: def photos(user_id, file_name):
    upload_url = vk.method("photos.getMessagesUploadServer")['upload_url']
    rs = requests.post(upload_url, files={'photo': open(file_name, 'rb')}).json()
    data = vk.method('photos.saveMessagesPhoto', **rs)[0]

    attachment = "photo{}_{}".format(data["owner_id"], data["id"])
    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": user_id, "attachment": attachment})

file_name = random.choice(glob.glob('C:\extracted_images/*.png'))
...
;elif body == "фото":
   photos(user_id, file_name);

Вот так выглядит и выдает ошибку "unresolved reference user_id"

Comment: @Dаниил, или создайте переменную user_id с тем user_id, что вы использовали или вместо user_id передавайте значение, например: `user_id = 1` или сразу `photos(1, file_name)`

Comment: elif body == "фото":
def photos(user_id, file_name):
....

                    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": user_id, "attachment": attachment})

 user_id = id
                file_name = random.choice(glob.glob('C:\extracted_images\*.png'))

                photos(user_id, file_name)

Все равно не работает. Не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: Тут явно ошибка: `glob.glob('C:\extracted_images*.png')`. Советую, если что-то не получается, разбираете это на более мелкие части и с ними работаете. Например, с `glob.glob('C:\extracted_images*.png')`, тут путь неправильный, нужно `glob.glob(r'C:\extracted_images\*.png')`. Кроме того, тут используются слеши, которые экранируют и хоть glob умный, лучше или делать экранирование слешей `'C:\\extracted_images\\*.png'`, или использовать другой слеш `'C:/extracted_images/*.png'`, или использовать raw-строки `r'C:\extracted_images\*.png'`. Возвращаясь к теме небольших задач, проверьте работу

Comment: `glob.glob(r'C:\extracted_images\*.png')`, например выведите его результат в переменную `file_names = glob.glob(r'C:\extracted_images\*.png')` `print(file_names)`, убедитесь что результат именно такой, какой вы ожидаете, после переходите к следующей задачке -- вытащить случайное значение: `file_name = random.choice(file_names)` `print(file_name)`, проверили что оно работает, приступаете к следующей и так пока скрипт не заработает. И так в каждой задаче нужно делать. Если не дробить ее, то можно и не переварить :)

Comment: Рандомизация работает, но не работает сама отправка сообщения в ВК, не могу разобраться в этом

Comment: Сделал так, чтобы оно грузилось через страницу через VkUpload, он выдает мне photo{OWNER_ID}_{ID}, если же выводить это в "message", то он выдает мне photo{OWNER_ID}_{ID}, т.е. все верно, но само фото нельзя посмотреть "Ошибка доступа" и оно не прикрепляется, оно как бы есть, но его нет, его нельзя увидеть, но оно должно загружаться, ведь данные для photo{owner_id}_{id} он откуда-то берет

Comment: @Dаниил, тут я могу посоветовать попробовать проверенный код. У того модуля vk-api есть вспомогательный модуль для загрузки, включая картинок. И меня есть пример работы с ним https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/7a19723f4d57f1dab2f7c8a707459db0763253f1/vk_api__examples/send_images/main.py#L41 для отправки картинок в сообщении себе, и себе на стену: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/vk_api__examples/simple_wall.post_local_image/main.py#L21

Comment: @Dаниил, еще я заметил, что похоже ошибся в примере и нужно было просто передавать json (как словарь) из ответа, а не раскладывать его: `data = vk.method('photos.saveMessagesPhoto', rs)[0]` (код ответа обновил). Попробуйте код из комментария выше -- он должен работать. Если нет, то лучше задайте новый вопрос по этой проблеме, приложив ваш код работы с vk, т.к. текущий вопрос был про другую проблему